# Define render window

Tags: rendering

I am an absolute newbie, downloaded Blender yesterday. I use 3D CAD every day to create image intensifiers, cameras, ion & electron detectors with Autodesk Inventor. The Inventor rendering is fairly basic so I'm hoping Blender will give me a better result.

I've managed to work out how to get my 3D model into Blender by exporting from CAD as a .obj file then importing into Blender. It looks OK in the Blender window but my problem is that when I go to the render tab, only a small portion of my model is displayed. I've sat through several on-line tutorials but can't see anything that covers this.

How do I tell blender to expand the render window to include the whole model?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean the render turns out to be displaying only a portion of the object, rather than a full view, something like this:

[image]

To fix this, you will need to set up your camera properly.

1. Go into Object View and set up the viewport approximately to where you want to camera to be (or the angle of the object in the render to look like).
2. Once done, press **`Ctrl`** + **`Alt`** + **`Numpad 0`**. This will automatically tell Blender to snap the camera to your current view.
3. Now make necessary adjustments (pan, tilt, zoom, etc.) to the camera as required. You can even change the focal length by selecting the Camera object, going to the `Camera Properties` in the right sidebar, and using the `Focal Length` slider.

Comment: Hexed, thanks for your comment. I'm in Object Mode with the model looking how I want it. I press Ctrl+Alt+0 & the view recedes slightly. When I press F12 now to render image I get a blank screen.